# jQuery sortable live() not sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Please see this link here: http://jsfiddle.net/CK9uL/129/

I'm trying to drag items from the right into an itinerary on the left. When I add 3 or more items to one time slot (e.g. Afternoon) I cannot sort the items. I've tried using `.sortable('refresh')` but haven't had any luck.

Comment: That jsFiddle doesn't seem to do anything at all - what's it supposed to do?

Comment: Perhaps this one (an earlier version) explains it better: http://jsfiddle.net/CK9uL/110/ - When I drag the "Additions" over to the left, that can't be reordered!

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the "draggable" after a drop:

```
// set up droppable
item.droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.appendTo($(this).find('ul')).draggable('disable');
    }
});
```

It's saved as [revision 131](http://jsfiddle.net/CK9uL/131/) of your fiddle :-)